# SQL Insert with join?

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables
[First Table][1]
[Second Table][2]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkAL4.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2I4YN.png
The question I need to know is how do I insert into Table 1 with a value for score when I only have the email to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose the `id` are the same in both tables.

You can `INSERT` from a `SELECT`

```sql
INSERT INTO table1 SELECT id, 99 FROM table2 where email = "xxx";
```

With `99` the score to add and `xxx` the email